# Enforce functions to implement for template argument class?

Tags: c++, templates, code-generation

Should I define an interface which explicitly informs the user what all he/she should implement in order to use the class as template argument or let the compiler warn him when the functionality is not implemented ?

```
template <Class C1, Class C2> 
SomeClass
{
  ...
}
```

Class C1 has to implement certain methods and operators, compiler won't warn until they are used. Should I rely on compiler to warn or make sure that I do:

```
Class C1 : public SomeInterfaceEnforcedFunctions
{
   // Class C1 has to implement them either way 
   // but this is explicit? am I right or being 
   // redundant ?
}
```

Comment: You're being redundant.  If you try to call methods that C1 doesn't have, it won't compile, that should be enough.

Comment: @PigBen: I have to disagree. If you just leave it to the compiler, the user will frequently get a horrible, useless error message. With a bit of work at enforcing requirements yourself, you can improve that quite a bit.

Comment: @Jerry -- That's fair.  However, in my opinion, the time would be better spent learning to understand error messages.  They're not useless, only hard to decipher.  That skill can then be applied to understanding other errors such as those you get when you misuse the STL.

Comment: @PigBen: I have to disagree -- the "right" answer is for the STL implementation (to use your example) to *also* be written to check its parameters. IMO, there's no good excuse for subjecting users to the error messages typical with templates.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should use a `concept` to specify the requirements on the type used as a template argument. Unfortunately, neither the current *nor* the upcoming standard includes `concept`s.

Absent that, there are various methods available for enforcing such requirements. You might want to read [Eric Neibler's article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/09/expressive-c-why-template-errors-suck-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/) about how to enforce requirements on template arguments.

I'd agree with Eric's assertion that leaving it all to the compiler is generally unacceptable. It's much of the source of the horrible error messages most of us associate with templates, where seemingly trivial typos can result in pages of unreadable dreck.

Comment: one more doubt - do you know how can I find out which functions the code is actually generated for ? _if I have many funcs in templates but only using one of them(is there a nicer way than doing find for functions)_

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to force an interface, then why use a template at all? You can simply do -

```
class SomeInterface //make this an interface by having pure virtual functions
{    
    public:
        RType SomeFunction(Param1 p1, Param2 p2) = 0; 
        /*You don't have to know how this method is implemented, 
          but now you can guarantee that whoever wants to create a type 
          that is SomeInterface will have to implement SomeFunction in 
          their derived class. 
        */
};
```

followed by

```
template <class C2>
class SomeClass
{
    //use SomeInterface here directly.       
};
```

Update -

A fundamental problem with this approach is that it only works for types that is rolled out by a user. If there is a standard library type that conforms to your interface specification, or a third party code or another library (like boost) that has classes that conform to SomeInterface, they won't work unless you wrap them in your own class, implement the interface and forward the calls appropriately. I'm somehow not liking my answer anymore.

Comment: because I know *what* I want from the class but don't know how yet, so defer `hows` only define `what-all`

Comment: Which is ok. You declare the functions in SomeInterface as pure virtual methods, thus making it a pure interface.

Answer (score 1):

Absent of ***concepts***, a for now abandoned concept (pun not intended, but noted) for describing which requirements a template parameter must fulfill, the ***requirements are only enforced implicitly***. That is, if whatever your users use as a template parameter doesn't fulfill them, the code won't compile. Unfortunately, the error message resulting from that are often quite gibberish. The only things you can do to improve matters is to

1. describe the requirements in your template's ***documentation***
2. insert ***code that checks*** for those requirements early on in your template, before it delves so deep that the error messages your users get become unintelligibly. 
   The latter can be quite complicated (`static_assert` to the rescue!) or even impossible, which is the reason concepts where considered to become a core-language feature, instead of a library.

Note that it is easy to ***overlook a requirement*** this way, which will only become apparent when someone uses a type as a template parameter that won't work. However, it is at least as easy to overlook that ***requirements are often quite lose*** and put more into the description than what the code actually calls for.
For example, `+` is defined not only for numbers, but also for `std::string` and for any number of user-defined types. Conesequently, a template `add<T>` might not only be used with numbers, but also with strings and an infinite number of user-defined types. Whether this is an unwanted side-effect of the code you want to suppress or a feature you want to support is up to you. All I'm saying is that it is not easy to catch this.

I don't think defining an interface in the form of an abstract base class with virtual functions is a good idea. This is run-time polymorphism, a main pillar classic OO. If you do this, then you don't need a template, just take the base class per reference.
But then you also lose one of the main advantages of templates, which is that they are, in some ways, more flexible (try to write an `add()` function classic OO which works with any type overloading `+` in) and faster, because the binding of the function calls take place not at run-time, but during compilation. (That brings more than it might look like at first due to the ability to inline, which usually isn't possible with run-time polymorphism.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining in details, `confusion` -  an I do that, if I don't care about run-time overhead ? or its still  kind of a bad design. _asking this because, it hurts to think that someone has to know what to implement before they use and there is no clean way to let them know_ (my knowledge is limited, please throw in more concepts or points that I might have missed) many thanks.

Comment: @Gollum: Well, the question is this: If you make those functions virtual, why bother with a template? Classic OO run-time polymorphism would work with that. And it might be confusing to your template's users that types _not_ derived from your base class will work just as well. IMO, this basically boils down to a design decision. Do you want run-time polymorphism or compile-time polymorphism? Usually you want the latter for speed (compile-time binding and inlining, which `virtual` kills) and flexibility (duck-typing: support addition for everything that has `operator+` overloaded).

Comment: If you want the latter, you want the latter. Granted, with _concepts_ deferred to a future version of the standard, compile-time polymorphism lacks the ability to clearly state what types used for template arguments need to support. But that's the way C++ (currently) is. If you want compile-time polymorphism in C++, you need to put up with it.